# Internet Explorer 11 html text misaligned inside form field boxes - Internet Explorer 10 Works OK with no misaligment

Tags: internet-explorer

I have got a major problem with text mis-alignment in forms when using Internet explorer 11. This error is only appearing in IE 11 and not in IE 10 which works OK on all table forms. I have been banging my head against the wall with this issue. Please can you help me find a solution to this problem that I'm having. I have 2 screen shots that I can share by email, but at the moment Microsoft won't let me put the images into this box. I don't have any code to show just the 2 screen shot links. Please don't put a hold on this question as I need an answer.

Screen shot of IE 11 with text misalignment errors https://chris-positivelyonline.tinytake.com/sf/MTAyOTY0XzY4MDkyNQ

Screen shot of IE 10 with no text mis-alignment errors https://chris-positivelyonline.tinytake.com/sf/MTAyOTY3XzY4MDkyOQ

Kind Regards
Scott

Comment: What have you already tried? [See this article on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a single store, in the admin.

The most easy is to create a lang variable to show the phone number in the header of your website.

If you want to show this variable in the header of your website, you have to create the variable in the following file

catalog/language/english/common/header.php

and in others languages

catalog/language/OTHER_LANGUAGES/common/header.php

for example:

```
$_['phoneNumber']       = '4654454564';
```

Or if you preffer you can use any variable of these files that you nowadays don't use, to put your phone number.

Comment: Thank you for your reply talegna, I only know a bit of php and I had a look at those files, I am using rgen theme and the part I want to change is in the footer, its the default phone box from the settings. Does code have to go into the footer TPL as well?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

If you want to show this variable in the footer of your website, you have to create the variable in the following file

catalog/language/english/common/footer.php

and in others languages

catalog/language/OTHER_LANGUAGES/common/footer.php

If you don't know so much about opencart , I recomending you that uses any variable of these files that you don't uses nowadayes.

The theme is not a problem, the lang files are the same. :)